# Why is this command not capturing the STDOUT?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, tee

I have an executable used for running Valve dedicated game servers. When it runs, it logs its status to the terminal. I want to capture this output in a file while also seeing it.

`./srcds_linux -game tf +map cp_dustbowl -maxplayers 24 | tee -a mylogfile.txt`

The executable runs just fine, and my terminal is populated with the server logs in real time, but when I kill the server, `mylogfile.txt` is empty. Is it possible that I can see the logs from the executable but that it's not actually logging to STDOUT? I'm relatively new to bash/linux scripting. I am not trying to capture STDERR, although it does at least print some of the logs I'm seeing in my terminal to `mylogfile.txt`, but not nearly all of them.

Comment: Did you try to capture STDERR?

Comment: Could it be that the output is buffered due to performance? Maybe try `./srcds_linux -game tf +map cp_dustbowl -maxplayers 24 | stdbuf -oL tee -a mylogfile.txt.`

tee only captures STDOUT. If you also want STDERR add `2>&1`: `./srcds_linux -game tf +map cp_dustbowl -maxplayers 24 2>&1 | tee -a mylogfile.txt`

Comment: @MadsAkselsen While capturing STDERR does at least populate the text file a bit, its not nearly the amount of info I'd expect to see. Using your suggestions for the buffer didn't seem to do much either.

Comment: It's really not clear where the output is being sent if the program is using neither standard output nor standard error. Perhaps experiment with running under `screen` or Expect. But it's really a bug if the program doesn't adhere to standard conventions.

Comment: I have hesitantly reopened this but I don't think you will receive any useful answers without more information about what output exactly you are trying to capture.

Comment: The command certainly is capturing STDOUT. The better question is where does the `srcds_linux` application actually output things. It has three options: STDOUT, STDERR and explicitly re-opening it's controlling terminal. The third is a wrong thing to do for logs (it is often used for prompting for password), but without knowing more about the process it cannot be ruled out.

Comment: @JanHudec @tripleee So I played around with `screen` and just logging the entire output of the screen, that seems to work fine. My initial assumption was kinda what you mentioned about where does `srcds_linux` actually output things. I have no control over `srcds_linux`, but I do know its old and the documentation available is not great. I am pretty sure the third option you mentioned about reopening the controlling terminal is correct though, as you are able to administer commands.

Comment: Another possibility is that the command uses `isatty()` to choose its logging level.

Comment: Which signal  do you use to kill the server? What does the documentation tell you on how to kill the server? If the server has no chance to flush its buffers, or is written so badly that it does not flash them even if it gets the chance, it is not surprising that you loose data.

Comment: Also, be more precise when describing the problem. You write _it logs its status to the terminal_, but I don't think that the server really talks to the terminal; if it did, you would have no chance to redirect the output. From your description, it is most likely that the server writes to stdout, and saying this explicitly in your question, helps in finding the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to handle the Source Dedicated Server on Linux and to capture all of its output is to run it in a docker container, maybe using the existing image from https://github.com/Hackebein/docker-srcds .

If you use their `run` command but omit the `-ti` options, the container will attach both `STDOUT` and `STDERR` but will not attach `STDIN` and will not allocate a terminal - forcing the executable to output all of its stuff to the standard stream, that you can then capture.

Running in a container also allows you a lot more control, such as instructing the container to log to files or syslog.

Comment: If I do this, wouldn't that prevent me from issuing commands to the server?

Comment: If command are sent on STDIN, then yes. You can also attach STDIN without allocating an interactive terminal - but having the executable expect input from a terminal explains your difficulties with capturing the output - terminal interactive apps interact badly with stream capture.